# What do the items for the pet do?

Tags: the-sims-freeplay

In the updates to the items available for pets added in and around the *Toddler Time* update, the following items were added:

- **food and water dishes**
- **Frisbee**
- **toy lobster**
- **toy bone**
- **Dog House**

**What do these items do?**

Most of these items cost ridiculous amounts of lifestyle points (200?! 250?!! Shy of cheating/exploits or paying money, these goals would take most any free player 1+ months of playing or some very good luck with the dog.) and before I am willing to invest in them, like any reasonable individual, I'd like to know if they actually do anything at all.

The only difference I've seen with the food and water bowl that I've usually kept topped up is that the dog seems to defecate on the lawn now.

Do the dogs dig up more money or LP or something? I haven't noticed a difference from the food/water dishes - am I doing it wrong or just unlucky/unobservant?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it doesn't do anything. It's decoration to make your Sim seem more of a pet loving person. If you tap the dog house and you have 2 dogs, make them go to sleep together. The dogs will have sexual intercourse and you get puppies. You do have to complete the 'Pet Permit' quest though. It's unlocked at level 18. The puppies give simoleons. They rarely give LPs, but it's a better chance then the full grown dogs.

Answer (score -1):

I have a good dog that has given me many LPs so I bought him a food bowl. Expensive, but well worth it. Within two minutes he dug up TWO LPs! So I believe praising him and feeding goes a long way. Try it.

Comment: What happened after? Did he continue to get LPs at such a rate?